# Slot Machine GUI

Tags: java, swing

It's me again. We were tasked in our class to make a Slot Machine with 2 panels. Everything is working great except for the if else conditions. It seemed that the JOptionPane is not working or showing when it met the condition, but it shows no error in the console. I see the alert on the right it says that the JTextField is unrelated to String, but I converted the Random Number Integers to String to show it on the panel since it seemed that only String are accepted in JTextField. Please help! Thank you!

```
package slotMachineMain;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class slot1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    
    JButton button1;
    JTextField text1;
    JTextField text2;
    
    slot1(){
        
        Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("D:\\11.png");
        ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon("D:\\12.png");
        ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon("D:\\13.gif");
        ImageIcon image3 = new ImageIcon("D:\\14.png");

        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Take your Chance Here!");
        
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setIcon(image1);
        label1.setBounds(120, 10, 138, 87);
        
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
        label2.setIcon(image2);
        label2.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 290);
        
        text1 = new JTextField();
        text1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,80));
        text1.setFont(new Font("Elephant", Font.BOLD, 35));
        text1.setForeground(Color.white);
        text1.setBackground(Color.black);
        text1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        text1.setEditable(false);
        
        text2 = new JTextField();
        text2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,80));
        text2.setFont(new Font("Elephant", Font.BOLD, 35));
        text2.setForeground(Color.white);
        text2.setBackground(Color.black);
        text2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        text2.setEditable(false);

        
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        panel1.setBounds(83, 100, 90, 90);
        panel1.add(text1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        panel2.setBounds(207, 100, 90, 90);
        panel2.add(text2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        button1 = new JButton();
        button1.setBounds(152, 200, 75, 25);
        button1.setIcon(image3);
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(400, 290);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setIconImage(icon);
        this.add(panel1);
        this.add(panel2);
        this.add(button1);
        this.add(label1);
        this.add(label2);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Random rn = new Random();
        if(e.getSource()==button1) {
            text1.setText(Integer.toString(rn.nextInt((10-8))+8));
            text2.setText(Integer.toString(rn.nextInt((10))));
            
            if (text1.equals("8") & text2.equals("9")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU WIN A TOKEN!", null, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                
                }
            if (text1.equals("9") & text2.equals("9")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "JACKPOT YEHEY!", null, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
            
        }
}

}
```

Comment: 1) *"..it says that the JTextField is unrelated to String"* I'll bet it doesn't! Always copy/paste error and exception output! 2) *"It's me again."* .. again? Your profile only shows one question, no answers. Have you deleted previous questions, or had them deleted for you? 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with ..

Comment: .. layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a **JTextField** with a **String** by typing

```
text1.equals("8")
```

and so on...

You should instead do

```
text1.getText().equals("8")
```

(To extract the String from the JTextField) and get the desired functionality.